# How to pass sharepoint credentials in my code?

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, ssis, azure-data-factory

I have C# code that goes to all the libraries in sharepoint on-premises and gets all the files and put it inside an azure file share.

The thing is I am executing it from the azure ssisdb and I am getting an incorrect username and password whenever I try to do it. I think Azure SSISDB is using its own account for accessing sharepoint. I have tried set credentials option and define my  domain username and password but I am getting an unauthorized access. What can be wrong in this case?

Comment: A SQL database has two types of credentials 1) Database 2) Windows.  The best method is to use Windows credentials then you do not need to use a username and password.  It uses the default login credentials of the user that is logged in (or the owner of the service that is running).  To debug use SQL Server Management Studio and test that you can  login to SSMS.

Comment: But in this case the user that holds the access to the sharepoint is the domain user, I have tried running the package by logged in as the same domain user, but I am getting incorrect username password error.

Comment: Can you login using default settings using SSMS?  You need to get the login working as first step.  Check the type of credentials (windows or SQL).   Make sure the connection string does NOT contain the MDF file name.  You should be able to just connect to server without password.  The database owns the mdf file and does not allow it normal users to connect using mdf.  The DataBase name and Instance of database should be the same in the connection string as in the login window of SSMS.

Comment: Hi jdweng, we tried with the exact same credentials which we used to connect in our sharepoint, but its not getting through and we are getting the same error, as the username password is incorrect.

Comment: Is the sharepoint running as service with the service set to run as Admin?  From SSMS explorer the 2nd item Security : Logins will give a list of logins for the server.  The users either have to be placed in the SQL Logins or added to the Windows Login as part of the group.  When remote logins occur the Windows group account has to be on the SQL Server machine and the remote machine.  Windows encryption is used to transfer data from machine to machine which requires the same group on both machines.

Comment: Which SharePoint version? SharePoint is its own platform. You aren't supposed to access the undocumented tables. In any case, SharePoint uses Windows Authentication for data access which means you can't use an Azure Account to connect to an on-prem database, even if the username and password look the same. They are still different accounts. You could add a SQL User login manually and try extracting the data.

Comment: If all the replication-related questions are about *SharePoint*, they won't work. SharePoint is far more complex than a web app on top of a database. Each version introduces *big* architecture and schema changes too. What *does* work, is using the document URLs to retrieve the files and possibly upload them to another target. SharePoint also has its own replication/publishing mechanisms although setting them up is a complex process.